# Why does launching an application via gksu not work?

Tags: gedit

I am attempting to automount my backup drive on Ubuntu studio 16.04.1.

I type `gksu gedit /etc/fstab` in terminal and enter my password, but I cannot see the editor.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: have you installed `gksu`? what DO you see, if not gedit?

Comment: Sometimes gedit opens minimized on the launcher. Look for an icon of a piece of paper with written lines and a pen sticking out from it. If you see it click on it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have checked that gksu is installed 'sudo apt-get install gksu'. I am still unable to launch.  I type my password in (which is accepted) and nothing launches? (no new icons) I looked at another forum which mentioned that gksu is no longer recommended.  How are people automounting an additional drive on boot?

Comment: You can avoid using graphical text editors entirely as a workaround... I use `vim`, but most users would use `nano`, so: `sudo nano /etc/fstab` or `sudoedit /etc/fstab`

Comment: Use `sudoedit` instead. It prompts you for your password, copies the file, lets you edit the copy as the user (with the user's editor, running as the user) and copies the edited file back. This helps one avoid GUI-as-root, a known error. See `man sudoedit`

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  gedit was not installed!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because gedit wasn't installed as per questioner's admission: http://askubuntu.com/questions/866704/cant-open-gedit-in-gksu#comment1340887_866704

Comment: I see no reason for this to have been closed. The fundamental problem here is that the OP was unaware that `gedit` wasn't installed, because `gksu` failed silently instead of showing an error. I don't know if gksu never does that or only in some configurations, but it's rather common. This has happened to me many times over the years (well... at least ten times, I'd say), on several different machines with different Ubuntu releases and flavors. I've also seen it vex other users (not just the OP and me). I have [posted an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/867235). I very much hope we reopen this.

Comment: @user637049 I'm familiar with this problem and I hope this question will help others who experience it. So, although it's solved, can you [edit] your question to say if you saw anything at all happen after you entered your password? In particular, did you (a) see a dialog or any sort of notification telling you that gedit didn't exist, that there was anything wrong with your command, or any other error, or (b) any messages in the Terminal? I'm pretty sure the answer to both is *no*--even if I were't familiar with this, your description leaves little room for such things--but I want to be sure.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think it could be better closed as no-repro, but I personally think it should be closed.

Comment: @EliahKagan we've been closing questions as no-repro/went away on its own for a while now when it's turned out to have been something like the package wasn't installed in the first place.

Comment: @EliahKagan the problem with `gksu` isn't what the question is about though. Sure, it's a problem, but the OP's concern was the failure to launch `gedit`. You're XY-ing this from what the OP was originally asking.

Comment: [**I've posted a meta question about this**](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16536/when-do-we-say-a-problem-cant-be-reproduced) and removed a few of my comments since I think my meta post includes what's useful about them. (They can still be viewed in context in [this chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51095).)

Answer (score 5):

When you run `gksu` or `gksudo` and attempt to run a command that doesn't exist, you don't usually see an error message.

If the `gksu` and `gksudo` commands are not installed, you *do* see an error message when you try to run them, but if *the program you're trying to run* is not installed, you do not always see any error message.

I am able to confirm this by running a command that is not installed (`gksu blahblah`) on a Lubuntu 16.04 system where I know the `gksu` is installed and working.

The OP was able to solve the problem by [checking if `gedit` was installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866704/cant-open-gedit-in-gksu#comment1340887_866704) and, upon discovering it was not, installing it.

---

Besides running `gedit` as root with `gksu` or `gksudo`, another way to edit a system file with a graphical text editor is to use `sudoedit` (as [waltinator has suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866704/cant-open-gedit-in-gksu/867235#comment1340748_866704)) but set the `VISUAL` environment variable to the editor you want to use:

```bsh
VISUAL=gedit sudoedit /etc/fstab
```

- Setting `EDITOR` instead of `VISUAL` also works, provided that `VISUAL` is not also set; if `VISUAL` is set and not blank, its value takes precedence. `VISUAL` doesn't mean "GUI" here.

The filename your editor shows you for the file you are editing will be something like `fstab.XXEZgT6C`. This is because `sudoedit` makes a copy of the file, you edit the copy, and your changes (if any) are written to the file when you close the editor. The filename shown in the editor is the name of the temporary copy.

The editor itself runs as your user, *not as root*, and has your settings, which can be convenient. However, since the `sudoedit` command only completes and writes your changes once you have quit the editor (not just when you've quit the file in the editor but the editor is still open), you'll probably want to either

- not have that graphical editor already running when you run it, *or*
- use a graphical editor that is configured so that a new instance is created every time it is run (rather than a new tab or window in the original instance).

In some editors, you can change this in the settings.

Of course, your editor does still have to be installed for this to work. But (as with the `gksu`/`gksudo` way) the editor doesn't have to be Gedit; you can use any editor you like.